# Display Value of \def Command

Tags: macros

I am a new Latex user and am still feeling my way through the massive amount of rules to follow. I am trying to do the following:

```
\def\ErDeedABookA {18A-Book}
\def\ErDeedBBookB {18B-Book}
\def\ErDeedCBookC {18C-Book}
```

This is the code I used:

```
\newcommand{\Xslash}{\char`\\}
\def\LP {A}\\
\def\Er {\Xslash ErDeedABook}
\def\ebook {\Er\LP}
```

Display value of ebook: \ebook

I expected: "18A-Book" to be displayed but I got: `\ErDeedABookA`
I must be missing a step to tell Tex to give me the value of the command not the command?

Comment: `\Xslash` as defined above is explicitly to print a `\ ` not to act as an escape character.  you are looking for `\def\ebook{\csname ErDeedABook\LP\endcsname}`

Comment: note that neither `\def` nor `\char` are latex commands but tex primitives, they can be used with care but not normally something a "new LaTeX user" would use (neither is even mentioned in the official latexbook documentation for latex, for example)

Comment: also the intention appears to be to get `\ErDeddABookA` but you defined `\ErDeedAPageA`  did you mean "Book" in that command name?

Comment: David you are outstanding... my example was faulty but you still gave the correct answer. Do you have a simple way to step through the alphabet so that \Lp in my example would increment for each pass through a loop?

Comment: loads of ways `\newcounter{zz} \loop\csname\Er{\Alph{zz}}\endcsname\ifnum\value{zz}<26 \stepcounter{zz}\repeat`   for example

Comment: David, once again it work great but how do I get the loop counter to set my LP (see my initial example) with the alpha value. If I use \thezz it comes our numeric... Sorry for being so dense.

Comment: `\renewcommand\thezz{\Alph{zz}}` will make `\thezz` be ABC

Comment: Since you have provided the two piecies I though I could tie them together, but with no luck. I am trying to loop through the  "Text Generation Loop and have the the zz counter update the LP value so that I select different values on each loop. It looked easy to add the increment of the zz counter update at the point where the index counter is update but when I try to tie the XX and LP counter together I get errors... Below are the part I am using, any help would be greated appreciated. I will send my currently defined Text generation loop in the next comment.

Comment: \def\LP {A}
\newcounter{zz} \loop\csname\Er{\Alph{zz}}\endcsname\ifnum\value{zz}<26 \stepcounter{zz}\repeat
\def\Ebook{\csname ErDeedABook\LP\endcsname} 
\renewcommand\thezz{\Alph{zz}}
Value of ZZ or LP: \thezz
%Text gen
\def\LAST{3}
\newtoggle{flag}
\noindent%
\setcounter{index}{0}%
\togglefalse{flag}%
\whileboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}<{\LAST}}}{%
  \stepcounter{index} %
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}{>}{\LAST}}}{%
    \togglefalse{flag}}{}%
  \iftoggle{flag}{Line with value: \Ebook\\}{Line with value: \Ebook  \\}%
  \toggletrue{flag}% 
}% End loop
\\

Comment: oh I'd just added something before you posted that code

Comment: David, I did not see your post... the only thing I saw was a recommendation to go to chat, but I can't becaue I don't have enough reputations.

Comment: that's OK we were just writing at the same time, the site shows that you posted the comment a minute before I posted my edited answer, so I just meant I did't see your code comment until after i had added a version.

Comment: \newcommand\LP {A}
\newcommand\Er[1]{ErDeed#1Book#1}
\newcommand\AB {\csname\Er\LP\endcsname}


\newcounter{zz}
\setcounter{zz}{1}
\renewcommand\thezz{\Alph{zz}}
\renewcommand\LP {\thezz}
\newcommand\EBI {}
\newcommand\EBB {}
\newcommand\EBP {}

Comment: David, based on your previous help you loop it has work but I have run into another problem, most likely have to do with expand. The "empty" test always comes up false? Any help greatly appreciated.
\whiledo {\value{zz} < 4}%
{%
\ifcsempty {\AB}
{\renewcommand\Er[1]{ErDeed#1Inst#1}\renewcommand\EBI {\csname\Er\LP\endcsname} Instrument No. \EBI}
{\renewcommand\Er[1]{ErDeed#1Book#1}\renewcommand\EBB {\csname\Er\LP\endcsname} Deed Book \EBB, 
\renewcommand\Er[1]{ErDeed#1Page#1}\renewcommand\EBP {\csname\Er\LP\endcsname} Page \EBP}

  \stepcounter {zz}%
}

Comment: as you see code in comments doesn't really work you can't even see the extent of a `%` comment as linebreaks are gone. It is better to ask a new question as a new question where you can format a complete test example (you can refer to this question from the new question)

Comment: David, wll do... thanks for all of you helpful comments.

Comment: A new question using the title: Correct Use of \ifcsempty Command has been added as an adjunct to this series of questions.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Assuming you meant Book not Page in the A case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\ErDeedABookA {18A-Book}
\newcommand\ErDeedBBookB {18B-Book}
\newcommand\ErDeedCBookC {18C-Book}


\newcommand\LP {A}
\newcommand\Er[1]{ErDeed#1Book#1}
\newcommand\ebook {\csname\Er\LP\endcsname}

\ebook


or in a loop

\newcounter{zz}
\renewcommand\thezz{\Alph{zz}}
\renewcommand\LP {\thezz}

\setcounter{zz}{0}
\loop
\ifnum\value{zz}<3
\stepcounter{zz}%

Case \thezz: \ebook
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Comment: David you are outstanding... your revised example was right on target. Do you have a simple way to step through the alphabet so that \Lp in my example would increment for each pass through a loop?